# undefined method in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

OKAY, I'm trying to learn ruby/rails (I cut my teeth on C++ in 1993)

Can anyone tell me why this:

```
class FeedHolder
    @rssfeed
    @rss

    #attr_accessor :rssfeed,:rss

    def rssfeed
        @rssfeed
    end

    def initialize(feed,rss)
        @rssfeed,@rss = feed, rss
    end
end
```

which is populated like this

```
  @rssfeeds.each do |rssfeed|
    @myrssurl=rssfeed.url.gsub(/'/,"")  
    @rss=Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(@myrssurl) 
    @myfeedguy = FeedHolder.new(rssfeed,@rss)
    @myrsslist.push(@myfeedguy)
```

gives me this error

"undefined method `rssfeed' for #FeedHolder:0xa0a8bec"

when I do this?
BTW, it doesn't complain about the call to myfeedguy.rss even though it doesn't have a getter
and yes, I tried attr_accessor and a bunch of other things.

```
<% @myrsslist.each do |myfeedguy| %>
<% if(myfeedguy.rss == 0) then %>
        "No feeds to show"</br>
    <% else %>
        <%=myfeedguy.rssfeed%>

        </br>
            <a href='' onclick='showfeed("")'>x</a>
        </br>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

thx in advance
Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're on the right track. Does this example help?

```
class FeedHolder
  def initialize(feed,rss)
    @rssfeed, @rss = feed, rss
  end
  attr_accessor :rssfeed,:rss
end

@rssfeeds = %w(a b c d)
@myrsslist = []

def fetch_and_parse(rssurl)
  "Imagine this was fetched and parsed from: #{rssurl}"
end

@rssfeeds.each do |rssfeed|  
  myrssurl = rssfeed.gsub(/'/,"")  
  rss = fetch_and_parse(myrssurl) 
  myfeedguy = FeedHolder.new(rssfeed, rss)
  @myrsslist.push(myfeedguy)
end

require 'pp'
pp @myrsslist
```

Output:

```
$ ruby tmp.rb 
[#<FeedHolder:0x00000001b00800
  @rss="Imagine this was fetched and parsed from: a",
  @rssfeed="a">,
 #<FeedHolder:0x00000001b00738
  @rss="Imagine this was fetched and parsed from: b",
  @rssfeed="b">,
 #<FeedHolder:0x00000001b00670
  @rss="Imagine this was fetched and parsed from: c",
  @rssfeed="c">,
 #<FeedHolder:0x00000001b005a8
  @rss="Imagine this was fetched and parsed from: d",
  @rssfeed="d">]
```

Comment: 1.9.3p194 :016 > fh = FeedHolder.new("feed","rss")
 => #<FeedHolder:0xad7ab18 @rssfeed="feed", @rss="rss">
1.9.3p194 :017 > fh.rssfeed
 => "feed"

Comment: when I init the feedholder guy with strings it works. but I'm using objects (though a string is an object too, so idunno)

Comment: Can you give an example of a `FeedHolder.new` that fails for you?

Comment: when I init the feedholder guy with strings IN THE RAILS CONSOLE, it works. but not in my actual app.

Comment: myfeedguy = FeedHolder.new("test1","test2")

Comment: undefined method `getrss' for #<FeedHolder:0x9f800f8 @feedzirr="test1", @rss="test2">

Comment: If you search your code for `getrss`, do you get any results?

Comment: def getrss
   @rss
  end
 end

Comment: Your question is now too vague to answer -- getrss doesn't even appear in the code in your question. I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: duh. I didn't know that rails precompiles SOME code. Sorry my question was vauge... but all the clues were there... from the top of my post

class FeedHolder @rssfeed @rss

but the error said

"undefined method `getrss' for FeedHolder:0x9f800f8 @feedzirr="test1", @rss="test2" wrong variable - its @rssfeed and not @feedzirr ! Restarting rails server fixed it. Thank s